# CakePHP 2 form fields with same name

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a form with a select for my user to select his / her occupation, i it`s not listed there they can write it on a text field bellow.

The data saves corretly, but only for the text field, as it`s the last one, I believe.

I am using the same name for both field, which saves like this.

```
$this->data['Student']['occupation']
```

If the user find an option on the select and leaves the text field empty the data to my database is also empty.

how can I save the data from the field that has the value set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do change the name first:

In form you can put the select with the name "occupation" and the textfield with the name "occupation2".

Then in your controller you can do that:

```
$this->data["Student"]["occupation"] = $this->data["Student"]["occupation2"] == "" ? $this->data["Student"]["occupation"] : $this->data["Student"]["occupation2"];
```

This will verify if the textfield is empty, if is empty will use the select list option else will use the textfield value.